# Google cloud platform throws me API key error

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, google-natural-language

I am working on Google cloud platform (Natural Language processing and Vision API)

I set up google cloud API (PHP) and to further authenticate my requests google suggested me like below:

> First, ADC checks to see if the environment variable
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set. If the variable is set, ADC
>   uses the service account file that the variable points to.
>
> If the environment variable isn't set, ADC uses the default service
>   account that Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine, App Engine, and Cloud
>   Functions provide, for applications that run on those services.
>
> If ADC can't use either of the above credentials, an error occurs.

I created a service account and download JSON and stored it on my server as suggested

> After you've created the service account and set the environment
>   variable, ADC is able to implicitly determine your credentials

Still I am getting the API key error like below:

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Adding Screenshot of Env variable that i had set on my server

[image: ENV variable screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

setting up the env variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" under `"/etc/apache2/envvars"` solved the issue. spent a day on it. hope this helps fellow developers :)

Answer (score 0):

did you set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable? https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

Comment: attached screenshot of the same

Comment: Oops! i noticed my server is removing the ENV variables? don't know why?